# After screen shot unable to click on any other window or taskbar

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, screenshot, focus

So I have the screen shot (copy screen shot of area to clipboard) set to a hotkey which has been working for a couple weeks but now all of a sudden whenever I take a screenshot I'm unable to click on different windows, or the taskbar on the bottom, or the bar at the top where the power icon is. In order to switch the focus I have to use ALT-TAB or restart my computer. This just started happening recently, I haven't installed anything that should cause this.

My Ubuntu version is 20.04.3

Comment: Killing gnome-shell fixes the problem actually, it's a work around. Is there any way to view the logs for whatever service facilitates the screenshots?